# What makes a metal more inclined to bond covalently?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, covalent-compounds

Many metals form compounds with s-block elements that are essentially entirely ionic. However, elements like silver, copper, lithium and so on, can form bonds that are significantly covalent in character. What are the factors that govern whether a particular metal will bond with significant covalent character? Is this linked to hardness and softness?

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/429/why-do-magnesium-and-lithium-form-covalent-organometallic-compounds?rq=1, http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27735/why-does-silver-form-bonds-with-covalent-character?rq=1

Comment: That depends on compounds with which they create bonds and oxidation numbers.

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/9038/how-would-one-compare-the-magnitude-of-covalent-character-between-sncl4-and-snf2?rq=1, http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16261/metal-compounds-that-bond-covalently?rq=1