# How to apply the Fajans' rules?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond

Outside of bonds between metal atoms=metallic bonds, non-metals=covalent bonds (molecules), it is difficult for me to determine what kind of bond it is.
I know that in the rule metals and non-metals form ionic bonds and that the ionic part of such bonds increases with increasing electronegativity difference and that Fajans' rules states that large cations with small positive charge and small anions characteristically form ionic bonds. But to me all these measures seem very fuzzy. I can say that SnCl2 is more ionic than SnCl4 because of the smaller positive charge of Sn (when considered as a cation) in SnCl2 (Sn2+) compared to SnCl4 (Sn4+). But how do I know that SnCl4 is a molecule?

Are there clear rules for determining the type of bond? How to proceed if criteria of the Fajans' rule contradict each other and at what point is it no longer an ionic bond with covalent character but a covalent bond (for metal-non-metal bonds like SnCl4, would SnO be a molecule or salt?)?

Comment: These classifications are made by us and not by nature and whenever we humans do so there is always ambiguity regarding the borderline from which you can say that type of bind has changed. Rules like Fajan's rule help us the covalent character in different ionic bonds. Rules like this cannot tell you if something is too covalent to not be called ionic.

Comment: Note: Salt ≠ Ionic and Molecule ≠ Covalent.

Comment: See: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/9038/how-would-one-compare-the-magnitude-of-covalent-character-between-sncl4-and-snf2/9968#9968

Comment: Thank you for your help, so one can't be sure if a compound is covalent or ionic only looking at the chemical formula/geometry?